# Eclipse java lwjgl no lwjgl in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, lwjgl

I installed and putted lwjgl library and natives to /lib folder. On eclipse Java build path setted library location and native library location. When i try to run it on eclipse, it works, but when i export it as a runnable jar, it doesn't run, and throws error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.libr
ary.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at Main.start(Main.java:9)
        at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Tried to set run properties VM argument to -Djava.library.path="lib/" but it doesn't work too.

P.S. Tried to put the  native .dll's to same folder as the jar is and it works, but I want to .dll's to be in other folder.
   Thanks!

Comment: Please post the exact command you use to run the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. You can do it with custom .bat file and put there -Djava.library.path="lib/", but mine solution is to programmaticaly do that with next line:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib/");
```

Comment: where do you put this line?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JarSplice? It is a free Java .jar packaging program found here:

`Ninja Cave - JarSplice`

Follow the instructions. All the documentation is on this site. Just make sure that the JAR you use for your program is just an eclipse JAR file, not a runnable jar. When you start up JarSplice, add the appropriate Jars, Natives, define your main class, and simply create a runnable JAR. No need to set up VM configurations, and also you can export to Windows.exe, and MacOSX. If all goes well, you should have a double-clickable runnable jar. Hope this helps. It's how I've packaged LWJGL games in the past :)